# psql with '-c' option or '-f' option is not terminating properly

Tags: postgresql, psql

When I run a command such `psql -d database -c 'select * from table'` or `psql -d database -f sqlcommands` `psql` does not terminate cleanly. Interestingly piping the the contents of the file instead of using the `-f`option eg, `psql -d database < sqlcommands` doesn't display this behaviour.

I need to press the `q` key as required by `less` or `man` for the execution to finish and return to the command prompt?

Is that the standard behaviour? Are the some escapes required that will allow it to terminate cleanly?

Comment: Can you check logs? Maybe there are some info what happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to press the q key as required by less or man for the execution to finish and return to the command prompt?

Sounds like your terminal's pager is taking over the output: you can tell psql not to send its output to the pager when you're using the `-c 'select... '` invocation via:

```
psql --pset pager=off -d database -c 'SELECT * from TABLE'
```

You may also put the line `pset pager OFF` in the file `~/.psqlrc`, however it seems ~/.psqlrc directives are honored only in interactive mode, not for commands passed in via `-c '...'`. More great tips for non-interactive psql usage from [Peter Eisentraut](http://petereisentraut.blogspot.com/2010/03/running-sql-scripts-with-psql.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link. It was really going to cramp my style.